# Keycloak Cordova-Native get token using native http request

Tags: cordova, keycloak, cordova-plugin-advanced-http

Presently I am developing Cordova Native based Application.
Right now login part completed. but I am struck at getting token part. My Backend team is blocking all calls from localhost. I want to overcome this by using native http API Using **Cordova Advanced HTTP** plugin. i am looking for example so I can replicate it.

this is the code keycloak using.

```
function processCallback(oauth, promise) {
        var code = oauth.code;
        var error = oauth.error;
        var prompt = oauth.prompt;

        var timeLocal = new Date().getTime();

        if (oauth['kc_action_status']) {
            kc.onActionUpdate && kc.onActionUpdate(oauth['kc_action_status']);
        }

        if (error) {
            if (prompt != 'none') {
                var errorData = { error: error, error_description: oauth.error_description };
                kc.onAuthError && kc.onAuthError(errorData);
                promise && promise.setError(errorData);
            } else {
                promise && promise.setSuccess();
            }
            return;
        } else if ((kc.flow != 'standard') && (oauth.access_token || oauth.id_token)) {
            authSuccess(oauth.access_token, null, oauth.id_token, true);
        }

        if ((kc.flow != 'implicit') && code) {
            var params = 'code=' + code + '&grant_type=authorization_code';
            var url = kc.endpoints.token();

            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open('POST', url, true);
            req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

            params += '&client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(kc.clientId);
            params += '&redirect_uri=' + oauth.redirectUri;

            if (oauth.pkceCodeVerifier) {
                params += '&code_verifier=' + oauth.pkceCodeVerifier;
            }

            req.withCredentials = true;

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    if (req.status == 200) {

                        var tokenResponse = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                        authSuccess(tokenResponse['access_token'], tokenResponse['refresh_token'], tokenResponse['id_token'], kc.flow === 'standard');
                        scheduleCheckIframe();
                    } else {
                        kc.onAuthError && kc.onAuthError();
                        promise && promise.setError();
                    }
                }
            };

            req.send(params);
        }

        function authSuccess(accessToken, refreshToken, idToken, fulfillPromise) {
            timeLocal = (timeLocal + new Date().getTime()) / 2;

            setToken(accessToken, refreshToken, idToken, timeLocal);

            if (useNonce && ((kc.tokenParsed && kc.tokenParsed.nonce != oauth.storedNonce) ||
                (kc.refreshTokenParsed && kc.refreshTokenParsed.nonce != oauth.storedNonce) ||
                (kc.idTokenParsed && kc.idTokenParsed.nonce != oauth.storedNonce))) {

                logInfo('[KEYCLOAK] Invalid nonce, clearing token');
                kc.clearToken();
                promise && promise.setError();
            } else {
                if (fulfillPromise) {
                    kc.onAuthSuccess && kc.onAuthSuccess();
                    promise && promise.setSuccess();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I would like to get help to convert above code using **cordova-plugin-advanced-http** plugin

Thanks in advance.